# Making a PodSecurityPolicy but Official manual not working

Tags: kubernetes

I trying to make a PodsSecurityPolicy on my Kubernetes Cluster and I got a Official manual from [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/pod-security-policy/)

Itn't work: I made all steps on my Kubernetes Cluter, but I can't to get a Forbidden massage.

My Kubernetes-cluster:

```
nks@comp:~$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"18", GitVersion:"v1.18.0", GitCommit:"9e991415386e4cf155a24b1da15becaa390438d8", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-03-25T14:58:59Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.8", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"17", GitVersion:"v1.17.4", GitCommit:"8d8aa39598534325ad77120c120a22b3a990b5ea", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-03-12T20:55:23Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.8", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Steps in my case (I marked trhe places "(?!)" where I should get the Forbidden-message but didn't it):

```
nks@comp:~$ cat psp.yml 
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: nksrole
rules:
- apiGroups: ['policy']
  resources: ['podsecuritypolicies']
  verbs:     ['use']
  resourceNames:
  - example
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: nkscrb
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: nksrole
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
subjects:
- kind: Group
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  name: system:serviceaccounts
---


nks@comp:~$ kubectl apply -f psp.yml
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/nksrole created
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/nkscrb created
nks@comp:~$ kubectl create namespace psp-example
namespace/psp-example created
nks@comp:~$ kubectl create serviceaccount -n psp-example fake-user
serviceaccount/fake-user created
nks@comp:~$ kubectl create rolebinding -n psp-example fake-editor --clusterrole=edit --serviceaccount=psp-example:fake-user
rolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/fake-editor created
nks@comp:~$ alias kubectl-admin='kubectl -n psp-example'
nks@comp:~$ alias kubectl-user='kubectl --as=system:serviceaccount:psp-example:fake-user -n psp-example'
nks@comp:~$ cat example-psp.yaml 
apiVersion: policy/v1beta1
kind: PodSecurityPolicy
metadata:
  name: example
spec:
  privileged: false  # Don't allow privileged pods!
  # The rest fills in some required fields.
  seLinux:
    rule: RunAsAny
  supplementalGroups:
    rule: RunAsAny
  runAsUser:
    rule: RunAsAny
  fsGroup:
    rule: RunAsAny
  volumes:
  - '*'
nks@comp:~$ kubectl-admin create -f example-psp.yaml
podsecuritypolicy.policy/example created
nks@comp:~$ kubectl-user create -f- <<EOF
> apiVersion: v1
> kind: Pod
> metadata:
>   name:      pause
> spec:
>   containers:
>     - name:  pause
>       image: k8s.gcr.io/pause
> EOF
pod/pause created
nks@comp:~$ kubectl-user auth can-i use podsecuritypolicy/example
Warning: resource 'podsecuritypolicies' is not namespace scoped in group 'policy'
yes
(?!)
nks@comp:~$ kubectl-admin create role psp:unprivileged \
>     --verb=use \
>     --resource=podsecuritypolicy \
>     --resource-name=example
role.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/psp:unprivileged created
nks@comp:~$ kubectl-admin create rolebinding fake-user:psp:unprivileged \
>     --role=psp:unprivileged \
>     --serviceaccount=psp-example:fake-user
rolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/fake-user:psp:unprivileged created
nks@comp:~$ kubectl-user auth can-i use podsecuritypolicy/example
Warning: resource 'podsecuritypolicies' is not namespace scoped in group 'policy'
yes
nks@comp:~$ kubectl-user create -f- <<EOF
> apiVersion: v1
> kind: Pod
> metadata:
>   name:      privileged
> spec:
>   containers:
>     - name:  pause
>       image: k8s.gcr.io/pause
>       securityContext:
>         privileged: true
> EOF
pod/privileged created
(?!)
```

Can you help me, please! I have not idea what is wrong

Answer (score 3):

Your cluster version is v1.17.4 and the feature is beta in v1.18 , try after upgrading your cluster.

Also make sure admission controller is enabled for Pod Security Policies,

Comment: I tried to do it on another cluster, but the situation is the same.

`kubectl get nodes -> kbr-mst   Ready    master   43s   v1.18.6 -> kbr-wrk   Ready    <none>   11s   v1.18.6`

Comment: can you tell kubectl version output please , also are you on prem or on cloud ?

Comment: `kubectl version -> Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"18", GitVersion:"v1.18.6", GitCommit:"dff82dc0de47299ab66c83c626e08b245ab19037", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-07-15T16:58:53Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"} ->Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"18", GitVersion:"v1.18.6", GitCommit:"dff82dc0de47299ab66c83c626e08b245ab19037", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-07-15T16:51:04Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}`

It's my own cluser installed from https://packages.cloud.google.com to Centos 7

Comment: then the problem is with admission controller , read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60043866/kubernetes-psp-seems-not-to-affect-something

Comment: Yes, It's work now since I enabled a `PodSecurityPolicy` in `enable-admission-plugins`. Thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable a PSP support in a [admission controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/pod-security-policy/#enabling-pod-security-policies)

```
[master]# vi /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubeadm.kubernetes.io/kube-apiserver.advertise-address.endpoint: 192.168.100.50:6443
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    component: kube-apiserver
    tier: control-plane
  name: kube-apiserver
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  containers:
  - command:
    - kube-apiserver
    - --advertise-address=192.168.100.50
    - --allow-privileged=true
    - --authorization-mode=Node,RBAC
    - --client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt
    - --enable-admission-plugins=NodeRestriction,PodSecurityPolicy ## Added PodSecurityPolicy
    - --enable-bootstrap-token-auth=true
    - --etcd-cafile=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt
    - --etcd-certfile=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-etcd-client.crt
    - --etcd-keyfile=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-etcd-client.key
    - --etcd-servers=https://127.0.0.1:2379
...

[master]# systemctl restart kubelet
```

It'll be useful for PSP

```
[master]# kubectl-user create -f- <<EOF
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name:      privileged
spec:
  containers:
    - name:  pause
      image: k8s.gcr.io/pause
      securityContext:
        privileged: true
EOF
Error from server (Forbidden): error when creating "STDIN": pods "privileged" is forbidden: unable to validate agains                                                                                                                        t any pod security policy: [spec.containers[0].securityContext.privileged: Invalid value: true: Privileged containers                                                                                                                         are not allowed]
```

It's my case on a Kubernetes v1.18 - I can't try on Kuberentes v1.17 now